# MySQL DateSub inside loop

Tags: mysql, loops

I have a stored procedure like this :

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS storedprocedure; 
CREATE DEFINER = 'userid'@'%' PROCEDURE storedprocedure
(IN id int)
BEGIN

DECLARE cor int; 
DECLARE sup int; 
DECLARE faktur varchar(20); 
DECLARE ptgs int; 
DECLARE suppli varchar(50); 
DECLARE bag int; 
DECLARE brg int; 
DECLARE qty int; 
DECLARE beli int;
DECLARE net int; 
DECLARE oldbeli int; 
DECLARE oldnet int; 
DECLARE updhrg int; 
DECLARE ket varchar(100);
DECLARE idsisa int; 
DECLARE qtyterima int; 
DECLARE qtysisa int; 

DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN; 
DECLARE loop_cntr INT DEFAULT 0; 
DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0; 

DECLARE hitung CURSOR FOR 
SELECT 
aptlog_orderterima.corp, 
aptlog_orderterima.idsupplier, 
aptlog_orderterima.faktur,  
aptlog_orderterima.idpetugas, 
aptlog_supplier.supplier, 
aptlog_orderterima.idbagian, 
aptlog_orderterimadetail.idbarang, 
aptlog_orderterimadetail.beli, 
aptlog_orderterimadetail.net, 
aptlog_orderterimadetail.qty, 
aptlog_barang.beli, 
aptlog_barang.net, 
aptlog_barang.updatehrg, 
CONCAT(aptlog_orderterima.faktur,' From : ',aptlog_supplier.supplier) 
FROM 
aptlog_orderterima 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN aptlog_orderterimadetail ON (aptlog_orderterima.id = aptlog_orderterimadetail.idterima) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN aptlog_supplier ON (aptlog_orderterima.idsupplier = aptlog_supplier.id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN aptlog_barang ON (aptlog_orderterimadetail.idbarang = aptlog_barang.id) 
WHERE 
aptlog_orderterima.id = id; 

DECLARE sisaorder CURSOR FOR 
SELECT 
aptlog_orderdetail.id, 
aptlog_orderdetail.qtyterima, 
aptlog_orderdetail.sisa 
FROM 
aptlog_orderdetail 
LEFT OUTER JOIN aptlog_order ON (aptlog_orderdetail.idorder = aptlog_order.id) 
WHERE 
aptlog_order.corp=cor AND 
aptlog_order.stat=2 AND 
aptlog_order.idsupplier=sup AND 
CAST(aptlog_order.waktu AS DATE) >= CURDATE()-(SELECT pengadaan_param.nilai FROM pengadaan_param WHERE pengadaan_param.id=2) AND 
aptlog_orderdetail.sisa<>0 AND 
aptlog_orderdetail.idbarang=brg 
ORDER BY 
aptlog_order.waktu 
LIMIT 1; 

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND 
SET no_more_rows = TRUE; 

OPEN hitung; 
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO num_rows; 
the_loop: LOOP 

FETCH hitung INTO cor, sup, faktur, ptgs, suppli, bag, brg, beli, net, qty, oldbeli, oldnet, updhrg, ket; 

IF no_more_rows THEN CLOSE hitung; LEAVE the_loop; 
END IF; 

SET @awal = (SELECT aptlog_stok.qty FROM aptlog_stok WHERE corp=cor AND idbarang=brg AND idbagian=bag); 

IF @awal IS NOT NULL THEN 
UPDATE aptlog_stok SET aptlog_stok.qty = @awal + qty 
WHERE corp=cor AND idbarang=brg AND idbagian=bag;
INSERT INTO aptlog_kartustok(waktu, corp, idbagian, idbarang, qtymasuk, qtykeluar, qtysisa, idpetugas, ket) 
VALUES (now(), cor, bag, brg, qty, 0, @awal + qty, ptgs, ket); ELSE 
INSERT INTO aptlog_stok(corp, idbarang, idbagian, qty) 
VALUES (cor, brg, bag, qty); 
INSERT INTO aptlog_kartustok(waktu, corp, idbagian, idbarang, qtymasuk, qtykeluar, qtysisa, idpetugas, ket) 
VALUES (now(), cor, bag, brg, qty, 0, qty, ptgs, ket); 
END IF; 

IF updhrg=0 THEN 
UPDATE aptlog_barang SET 
aptlog_barang.beli=beli, 
aptlog_barang.net=net, 
aptlog_barang.updatehrg=1, 
aptlog_barang.ubahharga=ket, 
aptlog_barang.waktuubah=now(), 
aptlog_barang.idpetugasubah=ptgs 
WHERE 
aptlog_barang.id=brg; ELSE 

IF (updhrg=1) AND (beli > oldbeli) THEN 
UPDATE aptlog_barang SET 
aptlog_barang.beli=beli, 
aptlog_barang.belilama=oldbeli, 
aptlog_barang.net=net, 
aptlog_barang.netlama=oldnet, 
aptlog_barang.ubahharga=ket, 
aptlog_barang.waktuubah=now(), 
aptlog_barang.idpetugasubah=ptgs 
WHERE 
aptlog_barang.id=brg; END IF; 
END IF; 

SET @qty=qty; 

sisa_order: LOOP 
OPEN sisaorder; 
FETCH sisaorder INTO idsisa, qtyterima, qtysisa; 
IF @qty=0 THEN CLOSE sisaorder; LEAVE sisa_order; 
END IF; 

IF @qty <> 0 THEN 
IF qtysisa > @qty THEN 
UPDATE aptlog_orderdetail SET 
aptlog_orderdetail.qtyterima=qtyterima+@qty, 
aptlog_orderdetail.sisa=qtysisa-@qty 
WHERE 
aptlog_orderdetail.id=idsisa; 
SET @qty=0; 
ELSE 
UPDATE aptlog_orderdetail SET 
aptlog_orderdetail.qtyterima=qtyterima+qtysisa, 
aptlog_orderdetail.sisa=0 
WHERE 
aptlog_orderdetail.id=idsisa; 
SET @qty = @qty-qtysisa; 
END IF; 
END IF; 
CLOSE sisaorder; 
END LOOP sisa_order; 

SET loop_cntr = loop_cntr + 1; 
END LOOP the_loop; 

END');
```

My question :

1. The second loop work perfectly, but the first loop just work once.
2. But if I remove this line "CAST(aptlog_order.waktu AS DATE) >= CURDATE()-(SELECT pengadaan_param.nilai FROM pengadaan_param WHERE pengadaan_param.id=2) AND" from sisaorder all loop work perfectly...

So can anybody help me?

Comment: I've removed the `delphi` and `pascal` tags you included, as the question has absolutely nothing to do with either of them. Please only use tags that are actually relevant to your question. In this case, the question is strictly about MySQL.

Comment: If you use indentation in your code, it will probably become more readable.